# How can I do lengthy tasks in php while the max execution time is 30 seconds?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm parsing data from a text file to a mysql database. The problem is, after parsing a certain number of records (anywhere from 250,000 to 380,000) I get `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. I can work around this by splitting the file into smaller files, but this is a pain and I'd like to find a way to trick PHP into processing the whole file.

Is there a way to convince PHP to run lengthy processes, even though I don't have access to php.ini and can't change my maximum execution time?

Btw, [here's my parsing script](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/bulk-etym/blob/master/parse.php). Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my php code.

Comment: You can use ini_set() to change max_execution_time

Comment: Is [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) an option?

Comment: If performance degrades over time, try issuing a `COMMIT` every 100 records (or 1000 records or whatever works for you). You could also set your connection to auto-commit. How you do that will depend on the database library you're using.

Comment: If you don't have access to php.ini, you are probably on shared hosting. Your provider is likely to notice if you circumvent their CPU-usage policy. It may be better to avoid upsetting them, by rewriting your script to perform work in bursts.

Comment: @RoyalBg, `ini_set("max_execution_time",0);` seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may find you can improve performance by inserting rows several at a time. Try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO
    tbl_name (a,b,c)
    VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)
;
```

The number of rows you should group together will be best found by experimentation. It might be that the more you add in the one statement, the faster it will be, but equally that might be slow if you don't have auto-commit turned on.

As someone mentions in the comments, putting too many in at once may max out the CPU, and raise the eyebrows of the server admin. If this is something you need to be careful with on your host, try 200 at a time and then a small `usleep` between iterations.

It's worth looking at the connection to your database too - is this on the same server, or is it on another server? The connection may be slow. Add some timing for, say, how long 5,000 rows take to insert, and then play around to see how to reduce it.

Here's the [manual reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for `INSERT`; note that this is non-standard SQL, and it won't work on other database engines.